# Separate operators and operands with whitespace in Java

Tags: java

for example I have

```
String str = "1+2*-3/4-5"
```

I want to format my String **str** and store it to a new String **newStr**
so that my **newStr** will have a value of

```
1 + 2 * -3 / 4 - 5
```

what ive done so far so far produces this output

```
1 + 2 * - 3 / 4 - 5
```

using this code

```
for(int i =0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        perChar = str.charAt(i);
        if(perChar == '+' || perChar == '-' || perChar == '*' || perChar == '/'){
            newStr+= " "+perChar+" ";
            continue;
        }
        str+=perChar;

    }
```

Comment: Here's an approach: Have a boolean variable in your code that represents whether the next character you're expecting is an operator or an operand. If you're expecting an operand and you see a - symbol then you'll know it's for negation. Also, make sure you toggle your boolean appropriately. I'll leave the implementation up to you

Comment: look out for the corner cases as in **-3 + 4 * 5** as well

Comment: If you know regex, then this will do it: `str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)([-+*/])", " $1 ")`. See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/sB0bO4/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code here is a solution to your problem simply check if an operand is preceded by another operand and not add a space if that is the case.

```
    String str = "1+2*-3/4-5";
    String newStr = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        char perChar = str.charAt(i);

        if(perChar == '+' || perChar == '-' || perChar == '*' || perChar == '/'){
            if(str.charAt(i-1) == '+' || str.charAt(i-1) == '-' || str.charAt(i-1) == '*' || str.charAt(i-1) == '/'){
                newStr = newStr + perChar;
            } else {
                newStr = newStr + perChar + " ";
            }
        } else {
            newStr = newStr + perChar + " "; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

If you are looking to implement a calculator you should look into storing the operands in a data structure for easy access such as an array.

And look into converting your expression from infix into [postfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) as that may be of use to you.